# Can't start activity from onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` where I make request to server and download some data. And according to received data I start `Activity A` or `Activity B` in `onPostExecute()`.

The problem is that doesn't work. No errors, simply activity doesn't start. Seems like code isn't executed there at all.

```
private class LoadingAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        if (InternetConnection.isConnected(ActivityLoading.this)) {
            .....load data
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityLoading.this, getString(R.string.no_internet_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        isDone = true;
        return isDone;            
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void isDone) {
        super.onPostExecute(isDone);
        //if work is done
        if (isDone) {
            if (dwnlData.equals("success")) {
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLoading.this, ActivityNavigation.class));
        } else {
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLoading.this, ActivityAuthorization.class));
        }
    }
}
```

I call AsyncTask in `onCreate`:

```
public class ActivityLoading extends ActionBarActivity {
static boolean isDone = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

    new LoadingAsyncTask().execute();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the argument data type void to boolean

```
protected void onPostExecute(boolean isDone) {
    super.onPostExecute(isDone);
    //if work is done
    if (isDone) {
        if (dwnlData.equals("success")) {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLoading.this, ActivityNavigation.class));
    } else {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLoading.this, ActivityAuthorization.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try making isDone a boolean?

Edit - You could just make doInBackground return nothing, and stop using the argument in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Log.d() or Toast() inside those if{} blocks to verify that your conditions are true